# How to hide internal libraries in library

Tags: java, android, sdk, proguard

My Android library (we'll call MYLIB) has internal dependencies on library X. Is it possible to prevent users of MYLIB from directly accessing X?

The main reason I want to do this it prevent my library users from having to deal with conflicts if they are using a different version of X in their own code. I also don't want this dependency to be exposed because if I stop using X and a library user has code involving the version of X bundled in with MYLIB, their code will break.

I'm not sure what to search for on this issue, so all links are appreciated. My instincts tell me Proguard will be involved.

Comment: "Is it possible to prevent users of MYLIB from directly accessing X?" -- not without modifying X (e.g., `jarjar`).

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you mean by 'jarjar'?

Comment: https://github.com/shevek/jarjar, though I don't know if there's something newer that does the same thing.

Comment: @CommonsWare this looks like it would solve the issue of version conflicts. Based on the description, it still sounds like the renamed library could still be accessed (the classes would still be public). Any thoughts on visibility changing?

Comment: Is the term you are looking for "to shadow a dependency"?

Comment: Changing visibility may break the library. I recommend that you leave it alone.